# Overlaying transparent image over output of camera in opencv

Tags: opencv, overlay, alpha-transparency

I have transparent images [shown below] and I am trying to overlay it with [aishack.in](http://aishack.in/tutorials/transparent-image-overlays-in-opencv/) cvOverlayImage() function to overlay it on camera source

**cvOverlayImage()**

```
    void cvOverlayImage(IplImage* src, IplImage* overlay, CvPoint location, CvScalar S, CvScalar D)
    {
     int x,y,i;

      for(x=0;x < overlay->width -10;x++)
        {
            if(x+location.x>=src->width) continue;
            for(y=0;y < overlay->height -10;y++)
            {
                if(y+location.y>=src->height) continue;
                CvScalar source = cvGet2D(src, y+location.y, x+location.x);
                CvScalar over = cvGet2D(overlay, y, x);
                CvScalar merged;
                for(i=0;i<4;i++)
                merged.val[i] = (S.val[i]*source.val[i]+D.val[i]*over.val[i]);
                cvSet2D(src, y+location.y, x+location.x, merged);
            }
        }
    }
```

**calling cvOverlayImage()**

```
cvOverlayImage(image_n, neg_img, cvPoint(0, 0), cvScalar(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0), cvScalar(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1));
```

**Inputs to cvOverlayImage()**

1. Camera Capture

[image: Camera Capture]

2. Negative Image

[image: Negative Image]

**Output from cvOverlayImage()**

[image: Output]

As you can see I am not getting what I need.Please help me.

Comment: If your problem is because of the rectangle that ruins your image, than you should only overlay the pixels that are not white(if background white), otherwise you should make a mask of the image(maybe a Threshold above the background) and then overlay those pixels completely, replacing the ones under them. That should give a nicer result :)

Comment: you are right, but the glasses will still appear transparent :)

Comment: @Smash I didnt got what you commented...Have you tried what Adrian Popovici suggested...Please help with the code if you got through it...

Comment: @WasimKarani Where you able to really solve this?

Comment: @karlphillip No I didn't, else I would have posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't tested, but shouldn't S[i]+D[i] = 1 to preserve the total intensity ?

Answer (score 2):

One solution I used is to simply detect where the white is present and in those cases simply use the pixel from the source picture. Otherwise use the overlay picture's pixel. Worked well for me for a similar situation. Also, if the picture you load has the alpha channel and can be used as a mask, that's even better.

```
void cvOverlayImage(IplImage* src, IplImage* overlay, CvPoint location, 
CvScalar S, CvScalar D)
{
 int x,y,i;

  for(x=0;x < overlay->width;x++)
    {
        if(x+location.x>=src->width) continue;
        for(y=0;y < overlay->height;y++)
        {
            if(y+location.y>=src->height) continue;
            CvScalar source = cvGet2D(src, y+location.y, x+location.x);
            CvScalar over = cvGet2D(overlay, y, x);
            CvScalar merged;
            if(over.val[0] == 255 && over.val[1] == 255 && over.val[2] == 255 && over.val[3] == 255)
            {
                // White pixel so don't overlay
                for(i=0;i<4;i++)
                    merged.val[i] = (source.val[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                for(i=0;i<4;i++)
                    merged.val[i] = (over.val[i]);

            }

            cvSet2D(src, y+location.y, x+location.x, merged);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1...good thought...But if I would have got some code to do that, it will be more cool....

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is not addition but multiplication:

```
int multiplicator = over.val[i] / 255 // 0 for black, 1 for white
merged.val[i] = source.val[i] * multiplicator;
```

This way the pixel value will be the original value for a white overlay pixel and black for a black overlay pixel.